# receiving json from message body

Tags: java, ajax, json, jersey

I'm trying to send a json String from an ajax call to a jersey web service.  I've looked at many related questions and articles but I haven't been able to get anything to work.  When I watch my calls from fiddler I can see the json in the body but when the method is hit the String is blank.  Thanks for any help.

```
getFile: function() {
    var urlXls = 'http://localhost:8080/KodiakWebS/Kodiak/KodiakXls/generateXls';
    //var json =  '{"xls":[{"name":"Pokemon","row":[{"data":"Lugia"},{"data":"Charzard"}]},{"name":"Types","row":[{"data":"Special"},{"data":"Fire"}]}]}';   //encodeURI();
    var json = this.get('tempJSON');
    urlXls = urlXls.replace(/\s/g, "");
    $.ajax({
        url: urlXls,
        type: "POST",
        data: json,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', // ;charset=utf-8',
        success: function(json, status)
            window.location.assign(json.url);
            alert("yay");
        },
        error: function(xhr, err) {
           debugger;
            alert(xhr+ " || " + err);
        }
    });
},

@POST
@Path("/generateXls")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces({ "application/xls" })
public Response sendWorkBook(final String json) throws Exception {
    createWorkbook(json);
    FileOutputStream sprdSht = new FileOutputStream("WorkBook.xls");
    wb.write(sprdSht);
    sprdSht.close();
    System.out.println("all done");
    StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream outPut)
                throws IOException,
                WebApplicationException {
            try {
                wb.write(outPut);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new WebApplicationException(e);
            }
        }

    };
    return Response.ok(stream).header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename = egisDoc.xls").build();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working thanks to the suggestions from caprica and tinkering around a little bit.  Not much changed in my code but here it is.

```
@PUT
@Path("/generateXls")
@Consumes("text/plain")
@Produces({ "application/xls" })
public Response sendWorkBook(String json) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("json: " + json);
    createWorkbook(json);

getFile: function() {
    var urlXls = 'http://localhost:8080/KodiakWebS/Kodiak/KodiakXls/generateXls';
    //var json =  '{"xls":[{"name":"Pokemon","row":[{"data":"Lugia"},{"data":"Charzard"}]},{"name":"Types","row":[{"data":"Special"},{"data":"Fire"}]}]}';   //encodeURI();
    var json = this.get('tempJSON');
    urlXls = urlXls.replace(/\s/g, "");
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: urlXls,
        data: json,
        contentType: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',   // ;charset=utf-8',
        success: function(json, status) {
            window.location.href = json.url;
            //window.location.assign(json.url);
            //alert("yay");
        },
        error: function(xhr, err) {
           debugger;
            alert(xhr+ " || " + err);
        }
    });
},
```

now on to trying to download xls file my service creates, hopefully I won't need to ask how to get what I have working (but if anyone has a method they're proud of and would like to share you're more than welcome too).
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you say you consume application/json, then I think you need to provide a Java object to model the JSON you are supplying.

If you do just want the JSON as a String, then you need to consume text/plain.

I typically have this when I use JAXRS:

```
@PUT
@Path("entities")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public SomeDomainObject updateSomeEntity(SomeDomainObject someDomainObject) {
    // Whatever...
}
```

Where "SomeDomainObject" is just a POJO with getters and setters.

I normally use the JacksonJsonProvider implementation rather than the JAXB one, and the above style of controller works just fine with JSON marshalling for me. I don't even need to add any JSON annotations to the domain objects either.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.  I was able to get it to work with something a little different but you helped me go the right direction.  I'll post what did after my 8 hours are up.  Thanks for the help.